# Samba: share home directories when home directories are symbolic links

Tags: samba, symbolic-link, home-directory

I have set up a new Ubuntu 9.10 system for five users. In the system is a large LVM volume where all the data is to be kept. The main system disk is not for this purpose, so I attempted to move the home directories using

```
usermod -d /var/data/username -m
```

And started creating my shares for these new home locations. But then I thought: hey, Samba has built-in home directory sharing! So I enabled that, and it didn't work. The shares were not published to the network. Only the share for user 'owen' was published; his folder hadn't been moved.

So I thought: maybe Samba home sharing only works for default home locations, so how about I move the home directories back to where they were, and then make them symlinks.

```
root@boxenmkiv:/home# ls -l
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 brett brett   25 2010-04-03 08:48 brett -> /var/data/brett/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 carly carly   23 2010-04-03 08:48 carly -> /var/data/carly/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dave  dave    21 2010-04-03 08:48 dave -> /var/data/dave/
lrwxrwxrwx 1 kate  kate    23 2010-04-03 08:47 kate -> /var/data/kate/
drwxr-xr-x 4 owen  owen  4096 2010-04-03 08:44 owen
```

Like so. Still no go. The only users share which is published to the network is 'owen' who as you can see above has not had his home directory moved.

I have also added the following to my smb.conf

```
[global]
   follow symlinks = yes
   wide symlinks = yes
```

BTW this is the normal config for home shares:

```
[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes
   # to try and see them, I set browseable to yes
   read only = no
   valid users = %S
```

With no luck.

Am I going about doing this the entirely wrong way? Should I just give up and manually create shares for the users?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it: all I had to do was login to each user account once and now they are working.

The above references to symlinks in the [global] section are required.

Comment: Consider marking your own answer as accepted; it helps the SuperUser community. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)